# Passing tokens to a contract method

Tags: contract-development, tokens, contract-invocation

I am fairly new to smart contract development and am still trying to figure out the whole sending ETH/tokens to a contract thing. In an article I saw the following example of a contract's terminate method which would refund all tokens in the contract to the owner:

```
function terminate(IERC20Basic[] tokens) external onlyOwner {
        // Transfer tokens to owner
        for(uint i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            uint256 balance = tokens[i].balanceOf(this);
            tokens[i].transfer(owner, balance);
        }
        // Transfer Ether to owner and terminate contract
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
```

What I don't understand is - when the owner calls `terminate` what should they pass as `tokens` parameter? I would love to see a concrete example, it would help me wrap my head around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERC20 tokens are just contracts that keep track of balances, so to transfer tokens, you call the `transfer` method on one of those contracts.

This function can be read as:

"For each token smart contract, find the balance of this contract and then send the full balance to the `owner`."

To answer your question, what gets passed in is an array of *addresses*. Solidity implicitly casts those addresses and treats them as smart contracts implementing the `IERC20Basic` interface, which presumably is defined to include `balanceOf` and `transfer`, two standard ERC20 functions.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, those token addresses are the addresses of token contracts, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.